# How to apply a material to a noise zone?

Tags: materials

Hello Blender Stack Exchange people :)

I'm a huge beginner in Blender so excuse my question if it's dumb ^^

I've got this going right now :

[image: Frost marks on a lens]

[image: Frost marks material]

This might seem a little dumb, but I'm struggling to change the color of the lens ONLY on the spots covered by frost marks... Please help ? ^^'

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT : This question has been answered, but here's the .blend file with the old and the new (wanted) material :p

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dRe8yqqS7rkg7MBtvonnJbyI16xaO5yZ/view?usp=sharing) (forgive the name, I didn't have any idea of what I was going for when I started ^^')

Comment: Have you tried changing the color in the glass shader? if the frost marks you're talking about are the white parts in the lens I think it might be that color value you need to change.

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried it before. It changes both the colors :c I want the lens to stay the same "white" color while the marks are a little blue-ish.

Comment: Ok, can you attach the .blend file here? So that i can take a look at it.

Comment: Even though the question has been answered I'll attach it in about 3h30min when I get home, sorry for answering this slow ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Final]

Here are two ways of doing this, both are using **Color Ramp** with **Constant** value, and both can be changed to something else and with white value (from Color Ramp) you can control how much colour will affect area.

**Mask between two shaders:**

This is best option if you want to have not only different colours, but also different shaders assigned to "frosted" area.

[image: first]

**Different colours for one shader:**

This is best suited if you want only to change colours.

[image: second]